# Overlapping image in java

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to overlap two image. For that, I use JLabel and set an ImageIcon to it. I also have a JPanel using a gridlayout containing my images (like a tile-based map). So far, no problem and it works great.

The problem I encounter, is when I tried to overlap two image. For that, I tried with a JLayeredPane in the gridlayout and put two images (JLabel) in a different level. This method throws me this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

I made some research and tried to downgrade to jdk-6 instead of 7, cause it appears that in the jdk-7 it doesn't work well. The exception has now disappeared,  but nothing is drawn on the screen.

Then I tried a new method by creating a class that extends JComponent and I override the paintComponent() method. My class contain an arrayList of my images (JLabel) and in the paintComponent method, I iterate through the arrayList and call each label's paintComponent method with the Graphics object of my own class. The same exception is raised.

Here's a sample my paintComponent method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for(JLabel label : this.images) {
        label.paintComponents(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: `label.paintComponents(g);` That should be singular. i.e. `label.paintComponent(g);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can to use

1. [JLayer (Java7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) based on `JXLayer (Java6)`
2. [GlassPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)
3. [OverlayLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LayoutOverlaySample.htm)
4. [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

then you can (for example) moving or animate with [Icons / ImageIcons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) placed in [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: `JLayeredPane` is last of property, have to accepting that `JLayeredPane` miss `LayoutManager`, then you need use `setBound` for `Layer`, and put there `JPanel` or `JComponent`, for `Icon` in the `Jlabel `you haven't use `paintComponent`, read linked tutorial

Comment: Also consider `AlhpaComposite` if blending is desired.

Answer (score 2):

If overridding `paint` or `paintComponent` is an option then I would suggest you use the `Graphics` or `Graphics2d` APIs for drawing images:

```
g.drawImage();
```

It offers a lot more flexibility for what you need.